# I want to OR a column with a number and store it back in same columns based on multiple conditions in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table called DETAILS.

- if Flag is 1 -->00000001 //(1st LSB is set here)
- if flag is 2 -->00000010 //(2nd LSB is set here)
- if flag is 3 -->00000011 //(1st,2nd LSB's are set here)
- if flag is 5 -->00000101 //(1st,3rd LSB's are set here)

Sample data:

```
ID NAME     FLAG(int)         IS_LAST
--------------------------------------
1  sports   5  (0000 0101)       0     //1st,3rd LSB's are set
2  News     11 (0000 1011)       0     //1,2,4 MSB's are set 
3  Weather  24 (0001 1000)       1     //4,5 MSB's are set
4  IPL      32 (0010 0000)       0     //6th MSB is set
```

If 2nd LSB or 6th LSB of FLAG column or IS_LAST=1, then I want to OR the FLAG with 64 (0100 0000) and store the result back in to same FLAG column using UPDATE query.

I want the output like this:

```
ID NAME     FLAG(int)                     IS_LAST
-------------------------------------------------
1  sports   5  (0000 0101)(Not updated)       0     
2  News     75 (0100 1011)(updated)           0      
3  Weather  88 (0101 1000)(updated)           1     
4  IPL      96 (0110 0000)(updated)           0
```

Answer (score 0):

My SQL has a bitwise `or` operator - [`|`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-or), so this is just a straightforward `update` statement:

```
UPDATE details
SET    flag = flag | 64
WHERE  (flag | 2 > 0) OR
       (flag | 32 > 0) OR
       (is_last = 1)
```